# Do card view with Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

How can i make a `UITableView` like the picture on the post ?
 I want to replicate this `Flat Effect`, with spaces between the items.

**Result wanted :**
[image]

**Wath i have :**

[image: https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10942275_10205438115774113_705893212_n.jpg?oh=0a5f0a97e340ccbe4276f76bbb0fe7c7&oe=54C7FA7D&__gda__=1422376201_01e828a1869caea6a960f8ede9a590d0]

Comment: Check this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEuoaTF1bok

Answer (score 27):

You can use this cardview, tell me if it worked for you, it worked for me.

https://github.com/aclissold/CardView/blob/master/README.md

```
//
//  The MIT License (MIT)
//
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Andrew Clissold
//
//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
//  of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
//  in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
//  to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
//  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
//  furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
//      The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
//      copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
//      THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
//      IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
//      FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
//      AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
//      LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
//      OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
//      SOFTWARE.
//

import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CardView: UIView {

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 2

@IBInspectable var shadowOffsetWidth: Int = 0
@IBInspectable var shadowOffsetHeight: Int = 3
@IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? = UIColor.black
@IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.5

override func layoutSubviews() {
    layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)

    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = shadowColor?.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffsetWidth, height: shadowOffsetHeight);
    layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
    layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
}
```

}

Comment: Brilliant! - Thanks

Answer (score 13):

In the cell of the collection view, I've created another UIVIew and gave these properties.

```
cardView.backgroundColor = .white

cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0

cardView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

cardView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)

cardView.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0

cardView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
```

**The result that I have achieved is this -**

[image]

Comment: If this doesn't seem to be working for you.. please make sure the contentView's "clip to bounds" option is unchecked in storyboard (OR it is set to false in your code) e.g. put the following code in "cellForRowAt indexPath:" method                                                                                       cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = false

Answer (score 1):

This looks better suited to a UICollectionView where you can set the insets of your collection view item. Alternatively, you can create a view inside of your table view cell's content view and set up constraints pinning the edges of the view a set distance from the table view's edges

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a custom UITableViewCell. Then, you can add multiple UIViews to your custom cell and so you can reproduce a similar look. My attempt:

[image]

The Code for my cell:

```
import UIKit

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var startPreis: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var startPreisLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var aktuellerPreis: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var aktuellLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var meldenLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var meldenPreisLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var tagImage: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()


    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        println("selected")
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

   }
```

As you can see, there are different UIViews/UILabels in my CustomCell which I can access in my cellForRowAtIndexPath-method by just replacing the UITableViewCell with my Cell:

```
var cell:MyCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID)  as MyCell
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple UIView extension call this func like
yourView.cardView()

```
extension UIView{
    func cardView() -> Void {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    }
}
```